# Absolute extensors of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I want to prove that the only absolute extensors of $\mathbb{R}$ are the intervals.

To prove that any interval is an absolute extensor I do:

- For any closed interval $[a,b]$ I apply Tietze Theorem.
- For any open interval $(a,b)$, $(-\infty,a)$, $(a,\infty)$ and $\mathbb{R}$, I use the fact that they are homeomorphic to $(0,1)$.

Then I take $P\subset X$, $X$ normal and $f:P\longrightarrow (0,1)$ continuous. We consider the aplication $f:P\longrightarrow [0,1]$, which is also continuous. Applying Tietze Theorem we obtain $\bar{F}:X\longrightarrow [0,1]$ continuous. We take $F_1=\bar{F}^{-1}\left(\{0,1\}\right)$ and applying Urysohn's Lemma we obtain $g:X\longrightarrow[0,1]$ continuous with $g(F_1)=\{0\}$ and $g(P)=\{1\}$. Defining $F:x\in X\longrightarrow F(x)=g(x)\bar{F}(x) \in [0,1]$ we prove that $F(X)\subset(0,1)$ and that $F$ is an extension of $f$.

For intervals of the form $[a,b)$ I just use that they are retract of $(a-\varepsilon,b)$.

I think my proof is correct.

However I struggle to prove that they are the only absolute extensors of $\mathbb{R}$. I tried an approach similar to the one used to prove that only the intervals are connected in $\mathbb{R}$, but I couldn't prove it that way.

EDIT: $Y$ is an absolute extensor if $\forall\;X$ normal, $\forall F \subset X$ closed, $\forall \;f:P\longrightarrow Y$ continuous, then $\exists F:X\longrightarrow Y$ continuous.

Comment: Could you say what an absolute extensor is? I've never heard this before.

Comment: $Y$ is an absolute extensor if $\forall\;X$ normal, $\forall\; F \subset X$ closed, $\forall f:P\longrightarrow Y$ continuous, then $\exists\; F:X\longrightarrow Y$ continuous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to prove that "absolute extensors" are always path connected!
To do that, assume that $X=[0,1] $ and $P=\left\{0 ,1\right\} $. We know that $X$ is normal and $P$ is a closed subset of $X$.

If $Y$ is an "absolute extensor", given $a,b\in Y $, you can define 
$f: P\to Y $ such that $f(0) = a $ and $f(1) = b $.

By our hypothesis, there is an (continuous) extension $F: [0,1]\to Y $. This is a path connecting $a$ and $b$. Therefore $Y$ is path connected.

To complete the proof of this theorem, you have to know that $X\subset \mathbb{R} $ is connected if and only if $X$ is an interval (this is a trivial fact of the topology of the real line).

Comment: I am assuming that "absolute extensor" is what is described here: http://at.yorku.ca/cgi-bin/bbqa?forum=ask_a_topologist_2007;task=show_msg;msg=4366

Comment: Yes, that is the definition of absolute extensor that I have.